# Can you tell me which rule of tense is followed here?

Tags: tense

He requires 5 days more **to beating** him.
Why it not says 'to beat' him?Is it correct?

A similar one:It is not natural **to be talking** to a machinery.
'To talk' ?

Comment: Where did you read/hear those sentences?

Comment: in press reader website

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the first one, it should be
"He requires 5 days more to **beat** him. (assuming 'he' refers to one person and 'him' refers to another. In this wording, it would be present tense because of "requires". For it to be past, it should be "required". For it to be future, "requires"). Although, the word more should come before days. For a 'perfect' sentence: "he requires 5 more days to beat him"

As for the second one, neither is correct.
the last 2 words ruin the phrase.
it should be any one of these depending on the tense:
Past Tense:
It is not natural **to talk** to machinery(or a machine)
Present:
It is not natural **to talk** to machinery(or a machine)
Future:
It is not natural **to talk** to machinery(or a machine)

In some instances, such as in the machine one, the past/present/future sentences are the same. This is when you will have to add an extra few words if you are required to emphasise the tense (eg.to past tense, write after it "dont do it again". Present, "stop doing it". future dont do it again)

Learning the English language is very difficult (as is all languages) because there are no 100% defined rules. Rules regarding 'i before e except after c' has exceptions

Hope this helps :)